# Is the next C standard actively developed?

Tags: c, standards, c99

Is there currently a group working on the next C standard (by next, I mean after C99)? If so, **what are the features** likely to make it in?

Comment: There's C++0x that should come out sooner or later, but I don't know about anything for C.

Comment: It's already perfect.

Comment: Of course, I had a look at the Wikipedia page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C1X) but nothing in there seems really worth getting :(

Comment: There is no more innovation to be made in the world of C. That would be like trying to make a better 8-track. I think C99 will be the last standard.

Comment: @wwwww: Don't worry about comments at all; nobody gets any points from them. Upvote away.

Comment: I suppose that, by the nature of standards committees, we should already start calling it C2x...

Comment: @James, they said that about C89 too (and some still do).

Comment: @wwwww: the C1x stuff is new to me, but the `stdatomic.h` and `threads.h` should look interesting to anyone dealing with multithreading.

Answer (score 6):

there is something called c1x (still a draft)

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1425.pdf

Answer (score 1):

They are at least working with the C++0x group to keep the threading standards between the two languages compatible.  (Which also means that C will get a threading standard.)

Comment: In the process, they're taking a *massive* step backwards from pthreads, which is already excellent; while not solving a single one of the real problems that *do* exist with pthreads.

Answer (score -1):

According to the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C1X) (quoted by the OP), features include *“Removal of the `gets` function”*. What I find ridiculous is that, by the very nature of the C language, there are so so many ways to shoot yourself in the foot, and they remove exactly **one** of them.

Com'on, it's a grown ups' language! If you can shoot yourself in the foot, it's only because it has real firepower!

Comment: While you can shoot yourself in the foot with many functions in C, most functions have a way to be used safely. `gets` is the one library function that obviously has no safe way to be used.

Comment: gets() is like a cigarette. If used exactly as directed, it will kill you, eventually.

Comment: @Tim: exactly! were cigarettes outlawed in your part of the world?!